# STM32 - I²C Slave HAL Callback ACK

Tags: stm32, i2c, hal

> Objective: implement a single byte I²C slave on STM32.

> Materials: STM32L452RE Nucleo-64 board, HAL Library, CH341 USB-I²C adapter(1), Artix Linux with Runit, Rhode & Schwarz RTB2004 oscilloscope

## Question

**How can I control the slave ACK signal?**

As I will present, ACK is sometimes sent, sometimes not sent. My guess would be with `I2C_FIRST_FRAME`, `I2C_NEXT_FRAME` and `I2C_LAST_FRAME` - but they don't seem to have any effect!

## Minimal example

The following non-functional example should:

- receive `cnt` number and `cnt` bytes, storing them in a buffer;
- transmit `cnt` number and `cnt` bytes;
- keep updating UART output with current stored buffer.

7-bit slave address is `0x6E`.

```c
void HAL_I2C_ListenCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef* hi2c) {
    HAL_I2C_EnableListen_IT(hi2c);
}

void HAL_I2C_AddrCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef* hi2c, uint8_t TransferDirection, uint16_t AddrMatchCode) {
    if (TransferDirection == I2C_DIRECTION_TRANSMIT) {
        HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Receive_DMA(hi2c, &cnt, 1, I2C_FIRST_FRAME);
        HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Receive_DMA(hi2c, buffer, cnt, I2C_LAST_FRAME);
    } else {
        HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Transmit_DMA(hi2c, &cnt, 1, I2C_FIRST_FRAME);
        HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Transmit_DMA(hi2c, buffer, cnt, I2C_LAST_FRAME);
    }
}

void HAL_I2C_SlaveRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef* hi2c) {
}

void HAL_I2C_SlaveTxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef* hi2c) {
}

void HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef* hi2c) {
}

void buffer_print(const uint8_t buf[], const char* name, const size_t size) {
    printf("%-20s[ ", name);
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("0x%04X ", i);
    printf("]\r\n                      ");
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("  0x%02X ", buf[i]);
    printf("\r\n");
}
#define BUFFER_PRINT(buffer, size) buffer_print(buffer, #buffer, size)

int main() {
    //...
    HAL_I2C_EnableListen_IT(&hi2c3);
    while (1) {
        BUFFER_PRINT(buffer, cnt);
        HAL_Delay(100);
    }
}
```

How am I testing: with the following shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -e

bus=$(i2cdetect -l | awk '/ch341/ {gsub("i2c-","",$1); print $1}')
dev="6e"

echo "Bus is ${bus}"
[ ! -c "/dev/i2c-${bus}" ] && echo "Bus /dev/i2c-${bus} not found" && exit

i2cdetect -y ${bus}
if ! i2cdetect -y ${bus} | grep ${dev} >/dev/null; then
    echo "Device not found"
    exit
fi

dev="0x${dev}"
size=10

echo "Writing ${size} consecutive bytes"
i2ctransfer -y ${bus} w$(( size + 1 ))@${dev} ${size} 0x01+
echo "Reading bytes"
i2ctransfer -y ${bus} w1@${dev} ${size} r${size}
```

## Testing write operation

- No stretch
- Analog filter does not have an effect

[image: write operation]

*write operation*

- With `HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Receive_DMA()`, received buffer will show:

```
buffer [ 0x0000 ] <-- wrong cnt
           0x01   <-- correct value
```

- With `HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Receive_IT()`, received buffer will show:

```
buffer [ 0x0000 0x0001 0x0002 0x0003 0x0004 0x0005 0x0006 0x0007 0x0008 0x0009 ] <-- correct cnt
           0x00   0x00   0x00   0x00   0x00   0x00   0x00   0x00   0x00   0x00   <-- wrong values
```

ACK is *randomly* not sent.

[image: detail on write operation: ACK and NACK signs]

*detail on write operation: ACK and NACK signs*

ACK looks like this:

[image: detail on ACK sign]

*detail on ACK sign*

NACK looks the same like ACK:

[image: detail on NACK sign]

*detail on NACK sign*

Sometimes, no ACK will be sent:

[image: write operation without ACK]

*write operation without ACK*

Independent of ACK and NACK, reported `buffer` will be the same.

---

Thank you!

(1): [Used driver](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/i2c-ch341-dkms)

Comment: Those spikes on the first picture are very strange (SDA). Do you have a picture of the setup and maybe a short schematic?

Comment: Sorry for the (really) late comment. When you asked this, I've already moved on, so unfortunately I cannot provide any photos. I was also wondering that and came to the conclusion, that the digital probe is misinterpreting something.
I finished "solving" the problem, but I don't know how: I came back from something that worked and re-added my project to the minimal example.... Now it works, but I cant say how.

Comment: @tweak - Hi, If (as I understand your comment) your problem is solved, and you can't now provide any more info, then I recommend you delete your question (on a desktop web browser you should see a link marked "Delete" below the question, next to "Flag" - mobile browsers might not display it). That way, no-one else wastes time analysing a question that isn't going to go anywhere, potential solutions can't be tested etc. Thanks.